# utilizar fila de tabla para realizar filtrado de datos en la misma tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Hola Amigos, tengo la siguiente tabla**
la cual contiene 4 columnas, codComp -> codigo de comprobante , numComp -> numero de comprobante, codAnexo -> codigo de comprobante anexo, numAnex -> numero de comprobante anexo

| codComp | numComp | codAnex | numAnex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03 | 000001 |  |  |
| 03 | 000002 |  |  |
| 03 | 000003 |  |  |
| 07 | 000001 | 03 | 000002 |
| 07 | 000002 | 03 | 000003 |
| 03 | 000004 |  |  |

De la tabla anterior deseo obtener todos los comprobantes diferentes en su codComp != '07' y diferente al comprobante anexo.

Es decir de los dos comprobantes con 07 que tengo en mi tabla no quiero que se muestre los comprobantes anexados ni la (codAnex -> 03, numAnex->000002,000003), los comprobantes con código 07

**el resultado que quisiera obtener**

| codComp | numComp | codAnex | numAnex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03 | 000001 |  |  |
| 03 | 000004 |  |  |

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

En SQL puede usar `<>` Diferente A

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE codComp <> '07' and codComp <> codAnex
```